# PHP7, export mySQL to CSV dont show special characters correct

Tags: php, mysql, csv, utf-8

I have a html form that stores data to mysql. When special characters are used (øæå), it store the characters correcly in the database.

When i use a script to save the mysql table to an CSV file, the CSV file wont show special characters correct anymore.

Any ideas?

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $user, $password, $database, $port);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$csv_export = '';

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ".$db_record);
$field = mysqli_field_count($conn);

for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
$csv_export.= mysqli_fetch_field_direct($query, $i)->name.';';
}

$csv_export.= '
';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
$csv_export.= '"'.$row[mysqli_fetch_field_direct($query, $i)->name].'";';
}
$csv_export.= '
';
}

header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$csv_filename."");
echo($csv_export);
```

Comment: Try data might be treated differently while storing in csv. If it is a json column, try doing json_decode before saving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to declare mysqli_char_set by doing this:
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

Answer (score 0):

I assume your script to save the mysql to CSV is run in linux shell or windows command prompt. Problem could be that data stored to database uses different character-set than environment that your script uses.

Check in which format data is stored to database or change it to UTF-8:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

And make sure your script environment uses the same character-set. On Ubuntu linux putting following lines to the file **/etc/environment** might do the trick (da_DK is for Denmark as just a guess from your characters, you need to set it to one your characters use):

```
LC_ALL=da_DK.UTF-8
LANG=da_DK.UTF-8
```

Comment: Do not use that flavor of `ALTER` until you have confirmed that "Columns are `CHARACTER SET latin1` (etc) and correctly encoded as such. but want utf8/utf8mb4 without touching other columns".

Answer (score 0):

Without any symptoms, it is hard to say which of several fixes are necessary.  See [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for a list of possible symptoms, together with what causes them.

When loading via `LOAD DATA`, be sure to specify the character set of the data as part of the statement.

HTML forms should start like `<form accept-charset="UTF-8">`.

Do not do any `ALTERs` until you have confirmed that the chosen syntax will be helpful, not make things worse.